# Unset session valirable is not working some time in drupal with htpp and https

Tags: session, drupal

I am getting problem in using session variable. In chrome it's working but in Mozilla some time session data is being removed automatically.

I have tried all the way which i have gotten after search. But still I am getting problem. only some data from array is being removed.

I am using 5 form all form is placed on different pages. And all data is being saved in session. So, in some case some field value is being lost.

Comment: If you are in a hurry, try to provide as much info as possible. What have you tried so far? What forms? Sample code? Screenshot? Anything?

Comment: I have tried to change session variable in php.ini . I have also used
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor', 100);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 200000);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0);
$conf['https'] = FALSE;

I have used these variable in setting.php .

I have made simple form using form api. After submit I am saving value in session. So, in some case some value is being missed when i goes onto another page.